# Why is p = &var; different from *p = var;?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 3;
    int* p;
    
    //p = &a;
    *p = a;
    printf("%d", *p);
    
    return 0;
}
```

error code: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Q1. I know that pointers output the values of operands. Why is `p = &a;` and `*p = a` different?

Q2. When `int* p = &a;` is declared, does `p = &a`, not `*p = &a`?

Comment: While these aren't bad questions, they are answered by a [good reference book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `int* p` is an *uninitialized* pointer, and `*p = a` exercises it. **Undefined behaviour**. `p = &a` initializes it properly.

Comment: To me, this question basically says "I have no idea what pointers are or how to use them, and although I know there's a wealth of documentation that explains them in detail, I'm hoping that asking questions about buggy examples will be a shortcut to learning about them."  It won't. Spend your time reading a tutorial that covers pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that pointers output the values of operands. Then isn't `p = &a;` not also `*p = a;`?

Pointers don't "output" anything.  They store addresses.  As for the difference, this:

```
p = &a;
```

Takes the *address* of `a` and assigns it to `p`, while this:

```
*p = a;
```

Takes the *value* of `a` and assigns it to whatever `p` *points to*.  In the above, the dereference operator `*` basically means "get whatever this pointer points to".

This also means that if `p` isn't set to point anywhere, you trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.  In this particular case your code crashed as a result (probably due to attempting to access an invalid memory address), but there is no guarantee this will happen.

> When `int* p = &a;` is declared, does `p = &a`, not `*p = &a`?

The above declares `p` to have type `int *`, and initializes it to the address of `a`.  In this case `*` is *not* the dereference operator, but part of the type declaration of `p`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is `p = &a;` and `*p = a` different?

`p = &a` stores the *address* of `a` into `p`.

`*p = a` stores the *value* of `a` into the thing `p` *points to*.

After writing `p = &a`, the following conditions are true:

```
 p == &a; // int * == int *
*p ==  a; // int   == int
```

and the statement

```
*p = 5;
```

is exactly equivalent to writing

```
a = 5;
```

The *expression* `*p` basically acts as an alias for the variable `a`.

In your code, the line

```
*p = a;
```

gave you a segfault because `p` had not yet been assigned to point to a writable location.  Unless explicitly initialized, the contents of a local variable<sup>1</sup> are *indeterminate* — it could be anything.

> When `int* p = &a;` is declared, does `p = &a`, not `*p = &a`?

In a declaration the `*` is only there to indicate type; it does not dereference `p`, any more than `int a[N];` indexes into `a` or `void f(void)` calls `f`.  So the declaration initializes `p` with the result of the expression `&a` (which has type `int *`).

Declarations in C are composed of two main sections — a sequence of *declaration specifiers* followed by a comma-separated list of *declarators*.

Declaration specifiers include type specifiers (`int`, `char`, `float`), type qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`), storage class specifiers (`auto`, `static`, `register`), and a few others.

Declarators contain the name of the thing being declared, along with information about that thing's array-ness, function-ness, and/or pointer-ness.  In the declaration

```
unsigned long a[N], *p, f(void);
```

the declaration specifiers are `unsigned long` and the declarators are `a[N]`, `*p`, and `f(void)`.  The types of `a`, `p`, and `f` are specified by the *combinations* of the declaration specifiers and declarators, so the type of `a` is "N-element array of `unsigned long`, the type of `p` is "pointer to `unsigned long`", and the type of `f` is "function taking no parameters and returning `unsigned long`".

Remember that in a declaration the `*` operator is always bound to the declarator, not the type specifier.  The declaration

```
T* p; // for any type T
```

is always parsed as

```
T (*p);
```

meaning if you write a declaration like

```
T* p, q;
```

only `p` will be declared as a pointer; `q` will be declared as a regular `T`.  If both need to be declared as pointers, you'd write

```
T *p, *q;
```

---

1. Strictly speaking, we mean something with `auto` storage duration; declared within a block without the `static` keyword.